# React Axios: Upload Multiple Images using FormData()

Tags: reactjs, axios, multipartform-data, image-uploading, form-data

I'm trying to upload files to the back-end. but it fails

Basically I want to upload 11 images at the same time.

At first I do this

```
    const title, image1, image2, ... = this.state;
    axios.post(`myapi`, {title, image1, image2})
```

Here is my state of image 1:

[image]

It returns an error of 422 "the given data was invalid"; "image_1": The image field is required.

After several reads online, I found out that to upload and image, you have to use formData. So I tried doing this

```
const title = this.state.title;

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image_1', this.state.image_1);
formData.append('image_2', this.state.image_2);
...
axios.post(`myapi`, {title, formData})
```

I still get the same 422 error,

[image]

tried to console.log the formData

```
for (var fd of formData) {
  console.log(fd);
}
```

the results indicate the formData has been appended well. But somehow i could not upload it because it is "invalid data"

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/upload-files-with-ajax.html hope this can help you

Comment: @HardikChaudhary thanks for the reply! I tried adding the filename in the append, and it still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting the images to FormData but sending them as JSON.
You should include title in formData as well.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('title', this.state.title);
formData.append('image_1', this.state.image_1);
formData.append('image_2', this.state.image_2);
```

And send the data with header as `multipart/form-data`

```
axios.post(`https://api.cashless.vip/api/homepage`, formData, {headers: {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"}});
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

add the header {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"}